# Visual Studio - Debug Executable Specified in the Debug Profile does not Exist

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, build, project

I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld C# .NET Core Console Application and I get this error. Being fairly new, I couldn't resolve it upon trying certain things mentioned in another answer. Please guide me on how to resolve it.

The error I get is:

> The debug executable [PATH] specified in the [Project Name] debug profile does not exist.

[image: Visual Studio Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried multiple solutions for many days, but the only thing that worked for me was completely removing VS 2019 and then re-installing.

Answer (score 15):

For me, all I needed to do was modify the Project Properties (right click the project in the Solution Explorer --> Project Properties), then under the Application tab, select an appropriate Target Framework. It was unset for me by default.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Copy the "cli" folder and rename it to "cli_x64".

Comment: This actual worked for me. Thanks. If anyone is wondering where the cli folder is, in my case it is in User\AppData\Local\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\3.23.5\cli. I just changed it to cli_x64.

Answer (score 6):

I had this problem very recently with a fresh installation of Visual Studio 2022. The error occurred when I attempted to run a project with the 5.0 DotNet Framework specified instead of the default, which was 6.0.

I fixed the issue by modifying my installation with the installer and manually selecting DotNet 5.0 Framework to be installed, because apparently, it is not installed by default and only 6.0 is.

Answer (score 5):

### Solution for Azure Functions

1. Make sure you have `azure-functions-core-tools` installed.
2. Open up your project's properties, `right-click project root | properties | Debug`
   You should see this:
   [image]
3. Set the `Launch` to `Executable`
4. Set the `Executable` to the path of your `azure-functions-core-tools` executable - in `AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\azure-functions-core-tools\bin\func.exe`

Answer (score 5):

#### Solution for VS2022

Open project properties, navigate to Debug Section and change values

[image]

Comment: Better to use a relative path, though the UI doesn't make it obvious how to do so. Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/e0eEa.png

Answer (score 3):

Like others here, (I upvoted a couple other answers) I tried multiple things for days and days, with no luck.  In my case, a simple uninstall and reinstall of VS2019 didn't solve the problem.  For me, the issue started with the VS2019 16.9.3 update, when suddenly projects that built fine before reported compile errors. The bizarre errors involved not being able to find references that were clearly there.  I have a large solution with about 60 projects, of which 40 were .NET Framework 4.5.2, and 20 were .NET Core, a mix of 2.x, 3.x, and a few 5.x.  At first, the compile errors affected both .NET Framework apps and .NET Core apps.  I was not having this problem on my home computer, nor were my coworkers having this problem.

First, I updated all the .NET Framework apps in my solution from Framework 4.5.2 to 4.7.2.  This seemed to solve it for the .NET Framework apps.  However, the .NET Core apps still had ridiculous build errors, "System" not found, "NUnit" not found after creating a new test project using the NUnit3 VS template.

I tried tracking down potential NuGet configuration issues; I tried shortening the Win10 PATH statement, and nothing helped. Then, after the first uninstall/reinstall of VS2019 failed to make a difference, here is what I did that led to a successful result:

- Removed all NuGet packages from the computer, using Package Manager Console ([see instructions here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/managing-the-global-packages-and-cache-folders)).
  I used command: `dotnet nuget locals all -clear`
- Uninstalled VS2019, using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer" app
- Uninstalled VS2017, using the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer" app
- Note: DO NOT uninstall the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer" app yet!
- Uninstalled all other prior VS versions (I had some crud from 2010 and even 2008) using Apps & features
- Ran the VS "InstallCleanup.exe" tool described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/remove-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).
- Removed the "Microsoft Visual Studio Installer" app using Apps & features
- Uninstalled all .NET SDKs and APIs, using `--all` option with the .NET Uninstall Tool
  see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/uninstall-tool)
  and [here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-the-net-core-uninstall-tool-1-0/tabs=macos)
- Uninstalled any & all remaining VS-related items showing in Apps & features, including some very old SDKs and Toolkits that were somehow on the "developer clone" PC my company issues
- Downloaded and (re)installed the VS Installer tool
- Using the VS Installer tool, reinstalled VS 2019
- Reinstalled the VS extensions I use (I had captured my list of installed VS Extensions in screenshots before starting all this)
- Rebooted once more...

After all this, all the issues that weren't working, all the "Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?" errors were now gone!  Naturally, the needed steps will vary, based on your computer, and some of the steps I did may not have been truly necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by right clicking the project, then "unload project", then right clicking again, then "reload project". Then running the project again and the error should be gone, at least for me

Answer (score 2):

To solve your problem, you need to start a *VS2019* as administrator and with this the project build will work normally.

[image]

**Note**: In my case the vs2019 is professional.

Answer (score 2):

For me, a wrong -path in the projectname.csproj.user was the problem. This drive me nuts!
After deleting this file and rebuild the project, it finally worked.

Answer (score 2):

I’m using Visual Studio 2019 (version 16.10.2) on Windows 10. What fixed the issue for me was to:

1. Start a new project
2. On the menu titled “Configure your new Project” I unchecked the option that says “place solution and project in the same directory”, then click next
3. On the menu titled “Addition information”, I selected the current target framework, which was “.Net5.0(Current)”, then click create.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting this error is because you do not have an `exe` file in your `netcoreapp` folder. Try and create a new project called HelloWorld1 and if VS19 doesn't create the files, you will need to uninstall and reinstall the application.

Answer (score 1):

I had a duplicate .AssemblyInfo.cs file within my project (one in the bin folder and one outside). This file is auto generated so what I did was removed both files, cleaned the project, ran a restore and then a rebuild. Fixed my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Install .NET Core cross-platform development from the Visual Studio Installer in the Workloads tab.

Answer (score 1):

I have changed my solution name, it occurs this error. Then I changed all `using packagename` to correct one, then rebuild it. It works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

1. Check the output path of project (Project > right click Properties > Build > Output path)
   [image: Output_Path]
2. Go to Build menu > Configuration Manager. Check the myMLApp has "Build" checked
   [image: Build_projects]
3. Clean solution. Build solution.

> source [link](https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/575)

Comment: already had that settings and it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Open properties, project -> Debug -> open debug launch profiles ui -> change working director, set current debug folder.

Answer (score 1):

Check the error list, Form1 showing the error. Using "Show potential fixes", sorted out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was just that I accidentally  tried to open a project created in VS 2022 with Visual Studio 2017.