# Taking an intro to programming/VB.NET class and my professor can’t open my sample program

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio, debugging

Followed all the steps to make a basic calculator program using VB.NET Compressed the file and submitted it but my professor gets an error message when trying to open it. She has no idea why and says I must of done something wrong but when I run my code everything works fine. trying to find a solution online but there’s no clear solution.

this is what my professor sees when she opens my file
[image: this is what my professor sees when she opens my file]

Comment: We have no idea what Followed all the steps means. If you're the only one in your class who is having the issue, it unlikely that you Followed all the steps. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In this case, provide the steps that the teacher provided. Then provide the steps that you took. It's unclear if "yexin" is your user folder or your teacher's. It's possible that you sent your teacher a link to the file on your computer rather than the actual file. Another possibility is the anti-virus software.

Comment: We have no idea how you packaged and distributed your application But did you even search online for a possible solution? Look at the error message carefully. If you search "debug profile does not exist" here is one link that pops up: [Visual Studio - Debug Executable Specified in the Debug Profile does not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61140481/6843158). Not all answers are necessarily good but this is a start. Obviously you are not the only one experiencing this error.

Comment: https://youtu.be/tts97GvtPSQ this is the exact same program with the same steps I had to follow. “yexin” is my professors folder. I’ve tried to search for a solution and get mixed answers.

Comment: That video has nothing to do with the steps you took to send the file to your professor. What file(s) are you attempting to send to your professor (ie: entire solution, just the .exe, etc...)? Are you placing them in a .zip file? How are you sending them (ie: uploading the file on a website, sending the file to an e-mail address, etc...)?

Comment: I’m trying to send the entire solution. I zip the folder and submit on a website(blackboard).

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2017 community edition

Comment: Another reference you may need: https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-modelbuilder/issues/575

Comment: I tried something from another thread. I submitted it and waiting on my Professor to let me know if they can open it or not.