# The debug executable [PATH] specified in the [Project Name] debug profile does not exist

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, project

I am trying to run a simple HelloWorld C# .NET Core Console Application and I get this error. Being fairly new, I couldn't resolve it upon trying certain things mentioned in another answer. Please guide me on how to resolve it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ygXQ.png)

Comment: You can try to shorten the path to your exe file. There can be an error due to long file path sometimes. (meaning to move your project to `C:\Project` for example )

Comment: Is the path really correct?

Comment: Try shortening the path a bit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio - Debug Executable Specified in the Debug Profile does not Exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61140481/visual-studio-debug-executable-specified-in-the-debug-profile-does-not-exist)